# Why does GridLayout doesn't work on my real android device?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, grid-layout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO2Zd.png)

When I run on virtual device it works fine:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlLC0.png)

This is my gradle file

dependencies {

```
implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
```

}

Comment: which model sir

Comment: xiaomi 11t android 12 version

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_view"
    android:id="@+id/top_view"
    />

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/top_view"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:rowCount="5"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:layout_marginTop="-80dp"
    >

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="12dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Home"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="12dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_shop"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Shop"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="12dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Favorite"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="12dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Profile"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="12dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="0"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_notifications"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Notifications"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="12dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="1"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_logout"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Logout"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</GridLayout>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="User Dashboard"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    />
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@rahulbigv17/how-to-show-the-grid-layout-view-dynamically-as-well-as-add-one-line-of-code-used-then-convert-to-e916a30be74a